# Delete the selected item in forward_list C++

Tags: c++, algorithm, function-definition, erase-remove-idiom, forward-list

I need to somehow remove an element in a list if it is already in another list. I created a function but it doesn't work. Tell me how to fix it. thank you very much.

```
void compare(forward_list<string> list_1, forward_list<string> list_2) {

    auto prev = list_1.before_begin();

    for (int i = 0; i < Size(list_1); i++) {

        auto l_front = list_1.begin();
        advance(l_front, i);
        
        for (int j = 0; j < Size(list_2); j++) {

            auto l_front_2 = list_2.begin();
            advance(l_front_2, j);
            if (*l_front == *l_front_2)
            {
                l_front_2 = list_2.erase_after(l_front);
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: At least the function parameters should have reference types.

Comment: "but it doesn't work" - how it doesn't work?

Comment: @arnold Why is the function called "compare"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you are trying to remove elements from `list_2` that are found in `list_1`. But in this statement

```
l_front_2 = list_2.erase_after(l_front);
```

you are using the iterator `l_front` from `list_1` that does not make a sense.

Also if an element in `list_2` is removed then due to the expression `j++` in the for loop

```
for (int j = 0; j < Size(list_2); j++) {
```

the next element in the list will be skipped.

A straightforward approach can look for example the following way as it is shown in the demonstration program below.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <forward_list>
#include <iterator>
#include <algorithm>

void make_unique( std::forward_list<std::string> &list_1,
    const std::forward_list<std::string> &list_2 )
{
    for ( auto current = std::begin( list_1 ); current != std::end( list_1 ); )
    {
        if (std::find( std::begin( list_2 ), std::end( list_2 ), *current ) != std::end( list_2 ))
        {
            std::string s( *current );
            list_1.remove( s );
            current = std::begin( list_1 );
        }
        else
        {
            std::advance( current, 1 );
        }
    }
}

int main()
{
    std::forward_list<std::string> list_1 = { "A", "B", "A", "C", "D", "B", "E" };
    std::forward_list<std::string> list_2 = { "A", "B" };

    for (const auto &s : list_1)
    {
        std::cout << s << ' ';
    }
    std::cout << '\n';

    make_unique( list_1, list_2 );

    for (const auto &s : list_1)
    {
        std::cout << s << ' ';
    }
    std::cout << '\n';
}
```

The program output is

```
A B A C D B E
C D E
```

A much more simple function definition can be if to use the method `remove_if` or the general function `std::erase_if` introduced in the C++ 20 Standard. For example

```
void make_unique( std::forward_list<std::string> &list_1,
    const std::forward_list<std::string> &list_2 )
{
    auto found = [&list_2]( const auto &s )
    {
        return std::find( std::begin( list_2 ), std::end( list_2 ), s ) != std::end( list_2 );
    };

    list_1.remove_if( found );
}
```

Or if the compiler supports C++ 20 then

```
void make_unique( std::forward_list<std::string> &list_1,
    const std::forward_list<std::string> &list_2 )
{
    auto found = [&list_2]( const auto &s )
    {
        return std::find( std::begin( list_2 ), std::end( list_2 ), s ) != std::end( list_2 );
    };

    std::erase_if( list_1, found );
}
```

The both presented functions remove elements in `list_1` that are found in `list_2`.

Comment: I think it is easier to write it with `remove_if`. we can use just use `std::find` in predict.

Comment: @Afshin I was under the impression that he uses loops.:)